# Do you know why this code gives me these different result?

Tags: python, web-scraping

So, I have this scraping code for an Amazon page, but when I want to get the "src" attribute from an image, it gives me strange results (basically sometimes it gives me the right src and sometimes not).

I used this code:

```
srcImage = scraperObject.find(id=idFrontImage)['src']
print(srcImage)
```

and it gives me this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

that is wrong, or, this:

```
https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/519iCKXNl1L._SY264_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_ML2_.jpg
```

that is completely right!!!
The page is the same and it changes from a run to another...

ty for help

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: The first portion is the base64 encoded data of the image.  Your browser is able to render that as an image.  Essentially they encoded the data for the image directly into the page you scraped.

Comment: https://www.amazon.it/Max90-storia-emozioni-decennio-fighissimo/dp/8820070421/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&qid=1618042585&s=books&sr=1-1
that is the URL.
So what if I want just the pure src value? 
ty though

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometimes the Amazon server returns URL and sometimes base64 encoded image in `src=` attribute. But you can select other attribute (`"data-a-dynamic-image"`) where Amazon stores plain URLs:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.amazon.it/Max90-storia-emozioni-decennio-fighissimo/dp/8820070421/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&qid=1618042585&s=books&sr=1-1"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#imgBlkFront")["data-a-dynamic-image"])

# print image with highest resolution:
print(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)[0][0])
```

Prints all the time:

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/519iCKXNl1L._SX360_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg
```